# mysterious bug between c# minimal api & nodejs & react-native

Tags: node.js, asp.net, .net, react-native, minimal-apis

Something is really weird happening on my development setup. I am developing for IOS but using react-native but something is happening which is weird.

If I boot the app in my device, and try to fetch the localhost (192.168.10.180) in my computer in nodejs works fine however in dotnet gets a timed out error

I try to simplify the most the servers and even tried these two configurations:

```
const express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.post("/", (req,res) => res.send("Received"))

app.listen(5056, => console.log("server is running))
```

on .net

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());

app.MapPost("/", async () =>
{
    return Results.Ok("Hello");

});

app.Run();
```

while changing of course the launchSettings.json to bind

```
"applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:7108;http://0.0.0.0:5056",
```

Long story short: Nodejs works fine, .Net does not work and gets the timed out (505) error. I think there is a step of the .net I am forgetting but cannot find it on google or even chatGPT. Anyone has a tip?

Comment: Not an expert in react native - is there any chance it forces a specific HTTP version (the 3rd one) to be used?

Comment: @GuruStron That would have implications and not allow to connect to NodeJs. I am trying to get a hold of an android device to see if it is just from IOS, but this gets stranger and stranger day by day.